# Suite class not running second test class in espresso using junit4 android

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have write my test cases using espresso and ui automation in android. Now when I run my two different classes of test cases.It always gives error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: No activities found. Did you forget to launch the activity by calling getActivity() or startActivitySync or similar?

and does not run `MainActivity2Test` class. I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong. Search regarding this error also but not able to find any solution. Please help me.

AllTestsSuite.java

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses ({
        MainActivityTest.class,
        MainActivity2Test.class,

})
public class AllTestsSuite {

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest {
   UiDevice device;

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityRule = new ActivityTestRule(MainActivity.class, true, false);

   @Test
    public void test1_doLogin(){
        device = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());
        device.pressHome();
        device.wait(hasObject(desc("Apps")), 3000);
        UiObject2 appsButton = device.findObject(desc("Apps"));
        appsButton.click();
        UiObject2 appsButton1 = device.findObject(desc("MyApp"));
        appsButton1.click();
test2_emaillPass();
}
 @Test
    public void test2_emaillPass(){
}

}
```

MainActivity2Test.java

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivity2Test {
     UiDevice device;
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityRule = new ActivityTestRule(MainActivity.class, true, false);

    @Test
    public  void test3_productFamily(){
       onView(withId(R.id.list)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
       test4_Product();


    }
    @Test
    public  void test4_Product() {
        device = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());
        onView(withId(R.id.list)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
        device.wait(hasObject(By.text("First product")), 4000);
        test5_Detail();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is your problem:

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityRule = new ActivityTestRule(MainActivity.class, true, false);
```

The last `false` parameter states if the activity should be launched when the test starts, see the method signature:

```
public ActivityTestRule(Class<T> activityClass, boolean initialTouchMode,
        boolean launchActivity)
```

So you either change that last flag to `true` or you manually launch your activity in each test like this:

```
mActivityRule.launchActivity(null);
```

Comment: By making last flag true,by app is getting refresh many times.And also throwing NullPointer Exception